# Android studio cannot resolve method 'add(int,com.*...*.LoginFragment)

Tags: android

Im trying to use Fragments on my app, but for some reason i get this error "cannot resolve method 'add(int,com.*...*.LoginFragment). i dont know what to do. i havce tried to import android.app.v4.... but its still giving me that error.

**this is the code**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction; 
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;    
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability; 


      public class TemplateLogReg extends Activity implements Connector {
      private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
      private static final String TAG = "Login";
      LoginFragment lg;
      EditText userTxt, passTxt;
      Button ret, reg, loginBtn, btnNewUser;
      private RegisterUser regUser;
      EditText phone, email, password;



     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.template_log_reg);
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
          // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
          startService(intent);
      }


      reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);
       phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneEt);
       email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEt);
       password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEt);
      ret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ret);
      btnNewUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewUser);
      userTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
      passTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
      loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
      lg = new LoginFragment();
      lg.setInterface(this);

      /** this code show us the login page. 5 lines **/
       FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
       lg = new LoginFragment();
       lg.setInterface(this);
       ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, lg); // this line error
       ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are importing the wrong classes

Replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

with their v4 versions

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And make sure that `LoginFragment` is importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` itself.

Then, you probably should also not use the base `Activity` class.

```
public class TemplateLogReg extends FragmentActivity
```

Or if you are using the appcompat-v7 library, then

```
public class TemplateLogReg extends AppCompatActivity
```

> I have tried to `import android.app.v4....` but its still giving me that error.

To use the v4 `FragmentManager` class, replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: i have tired to change the imports but its still giving me the same error. Also tried to extends **FragmentActivity** to **TemplateLogReg** its just make full errors. and the **AppCompatActivity** does not change anything

Comment: Which `Fragment` class does `LoginFragment` extend? `android.app.Fragment` or the v4 version?

Comment: @BolandianEran One missing step from this answer. After doing the above changes you need to call `getSupportFragmentManager();` instead of `getFragmentManager()` in the `TemplateLogRegto` activity to properly return an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` that can be used with fragments from the support library.